# How to determine Number of neuron in hidden layer for classification

Tags: neural-network

I used Iris dataset for classification with 3 layer Neural Network 
I decided to use :
3 neurons for input since it has 3 features,
3 neurons for output since it has 3 classes and
In the hidden layer
**what is the best number of neurons to do classification in this case?**

Answer (score 1):

There is not a clear a answer for this question. You should try and evaluated how the models performs testing diffferents configurations. But, basically, the next two premises are followed:

- **More neurons per layer** --> more complex model, and probably you will
  obtain better accuracy.
- **More hidden layers** --> more complex model, and again, probably you
  will obtain better accuracy.
- **WARNING** Both approaches increase the chance of overfitting by increasing the complexity of model. You need to carefully evaluate them through statistically robust model selection procedures e.g. cross-validation

Be aware that incrementing the complexity of the model will increase the computational process and , as mentioned, be careful with overfitting.

I recommend try a small number of neurons first, and then, try to increase step by step seeing if some improvement is achieved in the model.

Answer (score 1):

And to automate the evaluations, you can use a tool like, Keras Tuner https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/

From their docs, an example setup would look like this.

The min-max value for the units is where you would tune it for your case.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch


def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step=32),
                           activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```